# Jenkins' response is "Only push event can be accepted."

Tags: jenkins, webhooks, devops, gogs

I want to start a Jenkins as soon as a tag is pushed on Gogs.

What I have already done:

1. I installed Gogs Webhook plugin on Jenkins and configured the secret
2. I configured webhook in Gogs to invoke Jenkins job

This works if I use push event, but when I try to use Create event I get the following response error :

```
{"result":"ERROR","message":"Only push event can be accepted."}
```

How can I do to pass tag version to the Jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [gogs-webhook-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gogs-webhook-plugin) only supports *push* events currently. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gogs-webhook-plugin/issues/34#issuecomment-372033260) for more details:

> Investigated the problem but Gogs isn't triggering the webhook. This issue is also reported here #5042. Secondly until now we only trigger on push events, see line 104 in the file GogsWebHook.java. If the Gogs issue is solved we can take a look if we can implement this in this webhook. Will close this issue.

Now that Gogs is triggering the webhook on tag creation, a contribution to add this feature would be very useful.